# Eigen SparseLU factorize issue

Tags: c++, eigen

I am using Eigen library, but the following code fails to compile:

```
Eigen::SparseMatrix<double, Eigen::ColMajor> test(100, 100);
Eigen::SparseLU<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double, Eigen::ColMajor>, Eigen::COLAMDOrdering<Eigen::DenseIndex>> test_slv;
test_slv.analyzePattern(test);
test_slv.factorize(test);
```

I am getting the following output:

c:\users\user\source\repos\cartel\cartel\include\eigen\src\core\solvetriangular.h(247): error C2280: 'Eigen::Block &Eigen::Block::operator =(const Eigen::Block &)': attempting to reference a deleted function
        with
        [
            Derived=Eigen::Matrix
        ]
c:\users\user\source\repos\cartel\cartel\include\eigen\src\core\block.h(143): note: compiler has generated 'Eigen::Block::operator =' here
        with
        [
            Derived=Eigen::Matrix
        ]
c:\users\user\source\repos\cartel\cartel\include\eigen\src\core\block.h(143): note: 'Eigen::Block &Eigen::Block::operator =(const Eigen::Block &)': function was implicitly deleted because a base class invokes a deleted or inaccessible function 'Eigen::BlockImpl::StorageKind> &Eigen::BlockImpl::StorageKind>::operator =(const Eigen::BlockImpl::StorageKind> &)'
        with
        [
            Derived=Eigen::Matrix
        ]
        and
        [
            XprType=Eigen::Matrix,
            Derived=Eigen::Matrix
        ]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Eigen::COLAMDOrdering` needs to have the same index type as `SparseMatrix`. Try either `Eigen::COLAMDOrdering<int>` or `Eigen::SparseMatrix<double, Eigen::ColMajor, Eigen::DenseIndex>`.

If you `typedef`ed your sparse matrix type, you can use `Eigen::COLAMDOrdering<SparseType::StorageIndex>` (if `SparseType` depends on a template parameter: `typename SparseType::StorageIndex`).

Comment: There is no any effect.